Wildfly 26.1.3 high memory usage when the web app usage is very low
The wildfly web service was down during the non-peek time of our web application. When I checked the wildfly logs, it says that java process has killed due to the out of memory issue. This is the relevant logs part taken from the wildfly-26.1.3 server log.
Apr  6 04:47:48 kernel: [15858]    89 15858    22999      257      46        0             0 pickup
Apr  6 04:47:48 kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 16155 (java) score 362 or sacrifice child
Apr  6 04:47:48 kernel: Killed process 16155 (java), UID 1001, total-vm:7198552kB, anon-rss:2815260kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Apr  6 04:49:44 dhclient[986]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to ............. port ......... (xid=0x380160d9)
Apr  6 04:49:44 dhclient[986]: DHCPACK from 172.17.1.81 (xid=0x380160d9)
Apr  6 04:49:44 NetworkManager[943]:   [1712359184.1425] dhcp4 (eth0):   address  .............
Apr  6 04:49:44 NetworkManager[943]:   [1712359184.1439] dhcp4 (eth0):   plen 28  ...........
Apr  6 04:49:44 NetworkManager[943]:   [1712359184.1443] dhcp4 (eth0):   gateway ...........
Apr  6 04:49:44 NetworkManager[943]:   [1712359184.1474] dhcp4 (eth0):   lease time .........
Apr  6 04:49:44 NetworkManager[943]:   [1712359184.1479] dhcp4 (eth0):   hostname ..........
Apr  6 04:49:44 NetworkManager[943]:   [1712359184.1483] dhcp4 (eth0):   nameserver ............
Apr  6 04:49:44 NetworkManager[943]:   [1712359184.1483] dhcp4 (eth0):   domain name .....................
Apr  6 04:49:44 NetworkManager[943]:   [1712359184.1501] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed bound -> bound
Apr  6 04:49:44 dbus[754]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Apr  6 04:49:44 dhclient[986]: bound to ........... -- renewal in 1405 seconds.
Apr  6 04:49:44 systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr  6 04:49:44 dbus[754]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr  6 04:49:44 systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr  6 04:49:44 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [eth0]: new request (5 scripts)
This has not been reported during the peek times.
I have tried increasing the java heap size from  512 M to 2024m. Except this, when running .jar file heap set to 1024m.
if [ "x$JBOSS_JAVA_SIZING" = "x" ]; then
#JBOSS_JAVA_SIZING="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
JBOSS_JAVA_SIZING="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
fi
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
JAVA_OPTS="$JBOSS_JAVA_SIZING -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
else
echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi
Sample
